# provided that or provide that (providing that)?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Page 6 in this source: http://www.fanniemae.com/resources/file/ir/pdf/stock-info/series_s_12062007.pdf

> > > In  particular,  our  outstanding  subordinated  debt  securities  provide  that  during  any  period  where  interest  payments  on  those  debt securities are deferred, dividend payments on our equity securities, includi
> > >       ng the Preferred Stock, may not  be paid.

It is `provide that` here.
In the dictionary it is `provided that` or `providing that`.
How to understand it?

Comment: (Supplementary to Jim Reynolds' answer:) *Provided that X* and *providing that X* are participle clauses (some would actually categorize them as preposition phrases!) acting as clausal adjuncts: they are in effect conditions (="If and only if *X* is true") modifying the sense of the main clause. In the sentence you quote *provide* is the verb which heads the main clause ("our securities provide *X*").

Answer (score 1):

It means that the securities (as contracts or legal agreements) *say, hold,* or *imply* (that) . . . (when something happens, something else cannot happen).

The definition is as given [here:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provide)

> 2 : to make a proviso or stipulation
>   *the Constitution … provides for an elected two-chamber legislature ...*

An additional definition with some examples is given [here:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/provide)

> 3 [INTRANSITIVE/TRANSITIVE] LEGAL to contain statements or plans that set conditions for dealing with a particular issue
>     **provide for:** The treaty provides for the immediate withdrawal of troops from the area.
>   **provide that:** Their contracts provide that they will be paid on the last day of the month.

ADDED: @StoneyB's supplementary comment is postpended here for convenience:

*Provided that X* and *providing that X* are participle clauses (some would actually categorize them as preposition phrases!) acting as clausal adjuncts: they are in effect conditions (="If and only if X is true") modifying the sense of the main clause. In the sentence you quote *provide* is the verb which heads the main clause ("our securities provide X").